# I need assistance with the link below. Basically, I want the cell **D3** to return t

Tags: google-sheets

I need assistance with the link below. Basically, I want the cell **D3** to return the value matching the data in cells, C3 and D2 from the table below.

[image]

Comment: Nothing is attached. No link.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You need simple `INDEX/MATCH` combination. Try-

```
=INDEX(C6:H12,MATCH(C3,B6:B12,0),MATCH(D2,C5:H5,0))
```